# Unpickling classes from Python 3 in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

If a Python 3 class is pickled using protocol 2, it is supposed to work in Python 2, but unfortunately, this fails because the names of some classes have changed.

Assume we have code called as follows.

Sender

```
pickle.dumps(obj,2)
```

Receiver

```
pickle.loads(atom)
```

To give a specific case, if `obj={}`, then the error given is:

> ImportError: No module named builtins

This is because Python 2 uses `__builtin__` instead.

The question is the best way to fix this problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem is [Python issue 3675](http://bugs.python.org/issue3675). This bug is actually fixed in Python 3.11.

If we import:

```
from lib2to3.fixes.fix_imports import MAPPING
```

MAPPING maps Python 2 names to Python 3 names. We want this in reverse.

```
REVERSE_MAPPING={}
for key,val in MAPPING.items():
    REVERSE_MAPPING[val]=key
```

We can override the Unpickler and loads

```
class Python_3_Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    """Class for pickling objects from Python 3"""
    def find_class(self,module,name):
        if module in REVERSE_MAPPING:
            module=REVERSE_MAPPING[module]
        __import__(module)
        mod = sys.modules[module]
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
        return klass

def loads(str):
    file = pickle.StringIO(str)
    return Python_3_Unpickler(file).load()
```

We then call this loads instead of pickle.loads.

This should solve the problem.