# Unpickle in python2 a sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier saved by python3

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pickle

I'm having a similar issue to [unpickle sklearn.tree.DescisionTreeRegressor in python 2 from python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720952/unpickle-sklearn-tree-descisiontreeregressor-in-python-2-from-python3), but the linked solution at stackoverflow.com/questions/1385096/ doesn't seem to work for me.

I'm having a similar issue when trying to use python2 to load a
sklearn RandomForestClassifier that I saved in python3.

I boiled it down to the core problem which is loading a structured numpy array saved to represent the nodes in a tree, which results in 
`ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling`.

I created a MWE.

In python 3

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
data = np.array(
    [( 1, 26, 69,   5.32214928e+00,  0.69562945, 563,  908.,  1),
     ( 2,  7, 62,   1.74883020e+00,  0.33854101, 483,  780.,  1),
     (-1, -1, -2,  -2.00000000e+00,  0.76420451,   7,    9., -2),
     (-1, -1, -2,  -2.00000000e+00,  0.        ,  62,  106., -2)],
  dtype=[('left_child', '<i8'), ('right_child', '<i8'),
  ('feature', '<i8'), ('threshold', '<f8'), ('impurity',
  '<f8'), ('n_node_samples', '<i8'),
  ('weighted_n_node_samples', '<f8'), ('missing_direction',
  '<i8')])

# Save using pickle
with open('data.pkl', 'wb') as file_:
    # Use protocol 2 to support python2 and 3
    pickle.dump(data, file_, protocol=2)

# Save with numpy directly
np.save('data.npy', data)
```

Then in python 2

```
# Load with pickle
import pickle
with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as file_:
    data = pickle.load(file_)
# This results in `ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling`

# Load with numpy directly
data = np.load('data.npy')
# This works, but wont help me load a pickled sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier
```

However this still doesn't make sklearn play nice between 2 and 3.
So, how can we get pickle to load this numpy object correctly?
Here is the fix suggested in the link:

```
from lib2to3.fixes.fix_imports import MAPPING
import sys
import pickle

# MAPPING maps Python 2 names to Python 3 names. We want this in reverse.
REVERSE_MAPPING = {}
for key, val in MAPPING.items():
    REVERSE_MAPPING[val] = key

# We can override the Unpickler and loads
class Python_3_Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def find_class(self, module, name):
        if module in REVERSE_MAPPING:
            module = REVERSE_MAPPING[module]
        __import__(module)
        mod = sys.modules[module]
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
        return klass

with open('data.pkl', 'rb') as file_:
    data = Python_3_Unpickler(file_).load()
```

This still doesn't work